# Extract anything between first underscore and last underscore with exceptions

Tags: r, regex, list

I have a list of strings:

```
str1 <- "core21_ap_202003.xlsx"
str2 <- "core21_ap_thailand_202004.xlsx"
str3 <- "core17_eay_201008_b.xlsx"

strings <- list(str1, str2, str3)
```

I want to extract "ap", "ap_thailand", and "eay". I have tried:

```
gsub("_[^_]*$|^[^_]*_","", strings, perl=T)
```

Output:

```
[1] "ap"  "ap_thailand"  "eay_201008"
```

Works for the first two occurences, but not the last one. I need "eay", not "eay_201008".

In other words, that a country name (here, Thailand) is extracted only if it exists, and then date should never be extracted.

Desired output:

```
[1] "ap"  "ap_thailand"  "eay"
```

Comment: untested `gsub("_([a-z_]+)_|.","\\1", strings, perl=T)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find everything to the first underscore followed by everything until an underscore and 6 digits followed by anything.  Keep the part between the undersores.

```
strings |>
  unlist() |>
  sub(".*?_(.*)_\\d{6}.*", "\\1", x = _) 
## [1] "ap"          "ap_thailand" "eay"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution using `stringr`. In this case, you can extract the string of interest using the look around operators, preceded `(?<=)` and followed `(?=)`. In this case, the regular expression extracts anything `.*` that is preceded by an underscore `(?<=_)` and followed by an underscore and six digits `(?=_[0-9]{6}`.

```
library(stringr)

strings |>
  str_extract("(?<=_).*(?=_[0-9]{6})")

# [1] "ap"          "ap_thailand" "eay"
```

Answer (score 2):

With the assumption that what you want to extract contains only letters and eventually underscores:

```
> m <- regexpr("_\\K[a-z_]*[a-z]", strings, perl = T)
> regmatches(strings, m)
[1] "ap"          "ap_thailand" "eay"
```

Why doing a replacement when you want to extract?

Answer (score 1):

```r
unlist(lapply(strings, function(s) strsplit(s, split = "\\d+_|_\\d+")[[1]][2]))

#> [1] "ap"  "ap_thailand"   "eay"
```